# Find the smallest positive integer $n$ so that $2^{1989}$ divides $m^n - 1$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $m > 1$ be a positive odd integer. Find the smallest positive integer $n$ so that $2^{1989}$ divides $m^n - 1$.

Obviously $n = \varphi(2^{1989}) = 2^{1988} $ works by Euler's theorem but it's (most certainly) not the smallest such $n$. One essentially needs to find the order of $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{2^{1989}}^*$, which divides $2^{1988}$. But I'm not sure if there's a good way to find this order for an arbitrary positive integer $m$. I believe $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}^*$ is isomorphic to $\langle -1\rangle \times \langle 5\rangle$ for $n\ge 3$, where $\langle a\rangle$ denotes the cyclic group $\{a^n : n\ge 0\}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}_{2^n}^*$. To show this, one would need to show that the order of $5$ is $2^{n-2}$ for such numbers.

Comment: Looks useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Powers_of_2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $2^{1989} \mid m - 1$, then $n = 1$. Otherwise, instead of group theory, consider using the [Lifting-the-exponent-lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma). In particular, because $2 \mid m - 1$ and $n$ is even (actually it's a positive power of $2$ since, as you've already stated, $\left(n = \operatorname{ord}_{2^{1989}}(m)\right) \mid \left(\varphi(2^{1989}) = 2^{1988}\right)$), then with the article's formula of

> $\nu _{2}(x^{n}-y^{n})=\nu _{2}(x-y)+\nu _{2}(x+y)+\nu _{2}(n)-1$

we get with $x = m$ and $y = 1$ that

$$\nu_2(m^n - 1) = \nu_2(m-1) + \nu_2(m+1) + \nu_2(n) - 1$$

We require this to be at least $1989$, which gives that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\nu_2(m-1) + \nu_2(m+1) + \nu_2(n) - 1 & \ge 1989 \\
\nu_2(n) & \ge 1990 - \nu_2(m-1) - \nu_2(m+1)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Thus, if we set

$$k = \max(1, 1990 - \nu_2(m-1) - \nu_2(m+1))$$

we then get that

$$n = 2^k$$